# Android: How to configure IP adress over USB

Tags: android, adb

I have a board that runs Android and has no screen nor keyboard or mouse connected to it. I'm wondering if it is possible to set the network configuration (IP address, subnet mask, etc.) for that device remotely using ADB or other tools. An USB connection between the Android board and a second computer can be provided and the device is rooted.

Thanks for any help.

PS: I don't want to use ADB over TCP - that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using one of those apps from the Google Play store

- [VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schumi.vncs&hl=en) (best performance and supports start-on-boot)
- [droid VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&hl=en) (slow and system hangs sometimes)

Another cool tool is the [Android Screen Monitor](https://code.google.com/p/android-screen-monitor/) which uses the ADB connection over USB. But I could not get keyboard/mouse support running.